# Use custom taxonomy terms as parent for pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy

**Current situation**
We have a custom post type 'coupon', which has a custom taxonomy 'themepark' (hierarchical).

The taxonomy term pages are the most important pages on our website and are somewhat cornerstone content. An example of a themepark page is ourdomain.com/disneyland.

In the past, we created pages such as ourdomain.com/disneyland-address, ourdomain.com/disneyland-hotel and ourdomain.com/disneyland-pass.

After evaluating this structure for SEO, it seems we need to rectify this.

It seems better to adjust these pages and get these URL for them: ourdomain.com/disneyland/address, ourdomain.com/disneyland/hotel and ourdomain.com/disneyland/pass. Which would require them to become 'child' or sub pages of the taxonomy 'Disneyland'.

1. Do you think this is a good solution? This would make it more clear that '/disneyland/' is the main/cornerstone content and /address/, /hotel/ and /pass/ are subpages where people can find more information regarding Disneyland.
2. Is it somehow possible to add taxonomy terms to the 'parent' selection box in pages? This way the address,hotel and pass pages would automatically become subpages/child pages of the taxonomy term.
3. Is there an other way to achieve this permalink structure?
4. Would this work for having breadcrumbs like Home > Themeparks > Disneyland > Hotel ?

Answer (score 0):

- *Would this work for having breadcrumbs like Home > Themeparks > Disneyland > Hotel ?* - If you have a custom taxonomy that is named
  Themeparks, in that you have the main taxonomy term, and Hotel,
  Address, etc. are child terms.
- *Is there an other way to achieve this permalink structure?* - I believe you could use child pages.